# How to pass (update: Update, context: callbackContext) to my function without using Handlers

Tags: python, bots, telegram, handler, python-telegram-bot

I'm making Telegram bot for processing Youtube playlists.

I have 2 functions, and both of them have `(update:Update, context: callbackContext)` arguments.

The first function is called from main using messageHandler and it runs without errors.

But the second one is called from function 1.

I want to know how to pass those arguments without handlers. I want to say `function2()` in such a way that accept using `update.message` and other functions inside it.

Here is an example for the idea:

```
def check_url(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    get_videos_ids()

def get_videos_ids(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    some code that use upadte.functions

if __name__ == "__main__":
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, check_url))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass down the update and the context to the next function as such:

```
def check_url(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    get_videos_ids(update, context)

def get_videos_ids(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    some code that use update.functions

if __name__ == "__main__":
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, check_url))
```